# Why do i get an error when trying to console log value in $.each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, foreach

I am trying to loop through the values I have created in the array from vars.   Where the vars dont contain !"£$% etc... To console log

Uncaught ReferenceError: string is not defined

```
var string1 = "tes£$%t";
var string2 = "test";
var string3 = "test";
var string4 = "test";

var check_fields = [string1, string2, string3, string4];

$.each(check_fields, function(index, value) {

    if (value.replace(/^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i, "") != string) {
    console.log(value);

    }

});
```

Comment: first off u need to properly test for type of string

Comment: Use if (value.replace(/^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i, "").typeoff != 'string'

Comment: ` if (value.replace(/^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i, "") != check_fields[index])` Try that

Answer (score 1):

Your each loop needs to reference the string by using `check_fields[index]`like the code below. As `check_fields` is the name of the array, this is what you are looping over, and then checking each item in the array using `index`.

```
$.each(check_fields, function(index, value) {
    if (value.replace(/^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i, "") != check_fields[index]) {
        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

As stated by user @JCOC611 you could also use `value` as `check_fields[index]` is the same as `value`.

```
$.each(check_fields, function(index, value) {
    if (value.replace(/^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i, "") != value) {
       console.log(value);
    }
});
```

Comment: I mean you could also just use `value`, since `check_fields[index] = value`, but that works too.

Comment: @JCOC611 Added that to the answer, and gave you the neccessary attribution... good input! :-)